# Poles of the transfer function in Z Transform

Tags: z-transform, impulse-response, transfer-function, poles-zeros, complex

Given that:

- $H(z)$ has 4 poles maximum.
- $H(z)$ has a pole at $z_1=a+bi$

Given that the impulse response $h[n]$ is:

- Symmetric: $h[n] = h[-n]$
- Real: $\forall$$n$ , $h[n]$$\in$$\mathbb{R}$

How we can conclude that the other poles are the inverse and the complex reflection of $a+bi$ ?

Comment: Can you explain what they mean by a "real and symmetric transfer function"? It looks like the corresponding *impulse response* is real-valued and symmetric.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transfer function $H(z)$ is the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of the impulse response $h[n]$. If $h[n]$ is real-valued, i.e., if $h[n]=h^*[n]$ we have

$$H(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}h[n]z^{-n}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}h^*[n]z^{-n}=\left[H(z^*)\right]^*\tag{1}$$

So if $z_1$ is a pole of $H(z)$, then $z_1^*$ must also be a pole.

If furthermore $h[n]$ is symmetric, i.e., if $h[n]=h[-n]$ we have

$$H(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}h[n]z^{-n}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}h[-n]z^{-n}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}h[n]z^{n}=H\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\tag{2}$$

which means that if $z_1$ is a pole, then $1/z_1$ must also be a pole.

In sum, if $h[n]$ is real-valued and symmetric you get for each complex-valued pole $z_1$ three additional poles at $z_1^*$, $1/z_1$, and $1/z_1^*$